# How do I get form values to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on our new startpage that will show a filter and a list of news posts. Each news post, and each newslist can be tagged with several business areas.

The newslist will contain news according to:

- the settings of the newslist that can be altered by admins.
- then filtered by the filter form on the page.
- and, if the filter is empty but the user is logged in, filtered by the users preferences.

When the view **IndexSecond** is loaded, the filter gets its choosable business areas according to its newslist. My problem is that I don’t know how to get the selected business areas from the `EditorFor` to end up in the `model.filteredBAs` that is passed to **`IndexSecondFiltered`**?

When I come to a breakpoint in IndexSecondFiltered, the `model` is allways null.

**In the view IndexSecond**

```
@model Slussen.BLL.Models.PostFilterListModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexSecondFiltered", "Home", new { model = model }))
{
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.filteredBAs)
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-2">Business area</div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.EditorFor(model =>  Model.newslistModel.BusinessAreas, 
                                        new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
              <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary orange" />
          </div>
      </div>                
}
```

**In HomeController**

```
public ActionResult IndexSecond()
{
    //Known user?
    int? uo = null;
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        uo = CurrentUser.UserOrganization.Id;

    return View(
            _queryDispatcher.Execute<PostFilterListModel>(
              new GetFilteredNewsListById(1, uo, "", 1, 
                new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>(), 
                new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>())));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexSecondFiltered(PostFilterListModel model)
{
    //Known user?
    int? uo = null;
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        uo = CurrentUser.UserOrganization.Id;

    return View(
             _queryDispatcher.Execute<PostFilterListModel>(
               new GetFilteredNewsListById(1, uo, "", 1, 
                 new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>(), model.filteredBAs)));
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the `BusinessAreas` editor template?

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a collegue.

I didn't need the [HttpPost] ActionResult IndexSecondFiltered at all.

When I replaced this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexSecondFiltered", "Home"), new { model = model })
```

with this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexSecond", "Home"))
```

the model was passed to the controller along with IsSelected-status